# Cognito doesnt send SMS (SNS) in some countries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-sns

I have Cognito in the Frankfurt region, it uses SNS service in Ireland. So when I try to send the verification code from Cognito, I don't receive code in USA and Belarus, but get it in Israel and Canada. I've already created the Toll-free number for USA with transaction type and I can send messages using this number, but Cognito doesn't use this number. And I don't know what the problem with Belarus region, I suspect that I need to get senderId for it(maybe I need this for more than one region). What I need to do in order to Cognito start sending messages in all countries(At least in USA and Belarus)?